# How can I dump the seccomp filters installed while running the application?

Tags: linux, seccomp

Say I have a process with seccomp filters installed. At runtime, i would like to see all the seccomp filtered installed within this process.

How can I achieve that? Reading through seccomp man page does not seem to find the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ptrace(PTRACE_SECCOMP_GET_FILTER, pid, (void *)i, data)` where `i` is the index of the filter with the must recently installed being 0, and `data` is an array of `struct sock_filter` or `NULL` to read the size. The  return value is the number of instructions in the filter.